# У меня существует необходимость задавать формулу через консоль для программы и я бьюсь в вопросе, как это сделать?

Tags: c++

Пишу код в котором существует необходимость вводить формулу через консоль или же файл. В голове крутится мысль про массив и кучу возможных условий что бы можно было ввести формулу, но считаю это очень делетантская идея

Comment: а формула произвольная или нет? ну то есть, это просто обычный многочлен или нужно и сферический интеграл тоже нужно?

Comment: задача представляет из себя построение и последующий обход AST-дерева
https://edu.vsu.ru/pluginfile.php/80770/mod_resource/content/1/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%20%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0.pdf

Comment: По поводу синтаксического анализатора мысль хорошая